# Can't import blockchain.info api library for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, pip, blockchain.info-api

Using this github library: [blockchain.info python api](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python)

blockchain.py

```
from blockchain import Blockexplorer
block = blockexplorer.get_block('000000000000000016f9a2c3e0f4c1245ff24856a79c34806969f5084f410680')
```

When I run python blockchain.py in the command line on my mac I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blockchain.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blockchain import Blockexplorer
  File "/Users/mbp13/blockchain.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blockchain import Blockexplorer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Blockexplorer'
```

I checked if the blockchain module is installed by `pip freeze` and i see blockchain ==1.4.0 in the list. So i assumed it's installed

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# blockchain.py
from blockchain import Blockexplorer
```

I see 2 (two) problems here:

1. You script is called `blockchain.py` so `from blockchain import` tries to import from it instead of the `blockchain` package. Rename your script so it doesn't overshadow the package name.
2. You try to import `Blockexplorer` while the real module is lowercase. The correct import statement (after you rename your script) is

   `from blockchain import blockexplorer`